# t sql does code below a label execute if the label is not called from elsewhere in a trigger?

Tags: t-sql, triggers, label

The code below returns 2 datasets, "non-label" and "label area".  Does this behave the same way in a trigger?

I have a trigger that the area below a label does not seem to be executing when expected.

```sql
declare @var1 int = 3

if @var1 = 3
    begin
        select 'non-label'
        goto LBL
    end

LBL:
    select 'label area'
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. A label isn't "called" and execution will cheerfully proceed past a label. It isn't clear whether you are showing us code that causes a trigger to fire or is within a trigger. It seems that the answer is "yes".

Comment: From [`CREATE TRIGGER` Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments): "A trigger is designed to check or change data based on a data modification or definition statement; it should't return data to the user." _[sic]_ Where are you expecting multiple result sets from a trigger to go?